# How to create a Alphanumeric Serial Number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a alphanumeric serial number in Javascript, the serial number is governed by the following rules:

1. 3-Digit Alphanumeric Series
2. Allowed values 1-9 (Zero is excluded) and A-Z (All Capitals with exclusions of I and O)
3. The code should be able to give the next number after getting the input number.

The last part is tricky, basically the code would fetch the existing value of the serial number and it would then give the output as the next number.

For example: If the input number 11D then the output number should be 11E. Please let me know if this description is good enough to explain my requirement.

The excel sheet for the same is attached [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzoorscHTf6cckFxU0pZYlVGeDg/edit?usp=sharing)

Also the part of the code where the script would fetch the starting value 11D would be from this code:

```
cur_frm.add_fetch('item_group','serial_number','serial_number');
```

Comment: Why are you doing this with JavaScript? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: what happen when i input 99Z?

Comment: Your requirements seem relatively clear, but you haven't described your problem or your question. We'll *help* (and happily!), we're not, however, going to do all your work for you.

Comment: I am really sorry if it really seems like I am asking for my work to be done by other people. Basically I am not a coding guy and this is part of a larger code in an application which only accepts javascript any how I have added a link for the excel sheet where in I have made the series which is required by me.

Comment: @Ricky the next number after 99Z would be 9A1 and the last number of the series would be ZZZ. Since there are 33 variables in the series hence we would have 35937 possible values from 3-digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var alphabet = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var alphabetLen = alphabet.length;

    function nextDigit(digit) {
        nextDigitPos = (alphabet.indexOf(digit)+1) % alphabetLen;
        return alphabet.charAt(nextDigitPos);
    }

    /**
     * Computes the next serial id.
     * @param id the id to compute the successor of,
     *        if null or empty String the first id
     *        "111" is returned.
     */
    function nextSerial(id) {
        if(id==null || id.length==0) return "111";
        var digits = id.split("");
        digits[2] = nextDigit(digits[2]);
        if(digits[2] == "1") /* overflow */ {
            digits[1] = nextDigit(digits[1]);
            if(digits[1] == "1") /* overflow */ {
                 digits[0] = nextDigit(digits[0])
            }
        }
        return digits.join("");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
var nextSerialNumber = function(serialNumber) {
    return (parseInt(serialNumber, 36) + 1).toString(36).replace(
      /i/g,'j').replace(/o/g, 'p').replace(/0/g, '1').toUpperCase();
}

nextSerialNumber("99Z") //=> "9A1"
nextSerialNumber("11D") //=> "11E"
```

I'm not sure what you want to happen after `ZZZ`. It jumps to `1111`, but that could be changed.

If you input an invalid serial number (e.g. `11I`), it gives you the next valid number (e.g. `11J`).

Comment: Thanks jeff for the help, but the below mentioned answer helped me in dealing with the issue of the serial number reaching the value of ZZZ.

Comment: What is it that you want to happen at ZZZ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
function getNext(num) {
    var alphabet = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var digits = num.toUpperCase().split(""),
        len = digits.length,
        increase = true;
    if (len != 3)
        throw new Error("Invalid serial number length in getNext: "+num);
    for (var i=len-1; increase && i>=0; i--) {
        var val = alphabet.indexOf(digits[i]);
        if (val == -1)
            throw new Error("Invalid serial number digit in getNext: "+num);
        val++;
        if (val < alphabet.length) {
            digits[i] = alphabet[val];
            increase = false;
        } else { // overflow
            digits[i] = alphabet[0];
        }
    }
    if (increase) // is still true
        throw new Error("Serial number overflow in getNext");
    num = digits.join("");
    return num;
}
```

Since you are working with a nearly alphanumeric alphabet, a `parseInt`/`toString` with radix 33 might have done it as well. Only you need to "jump" over the `0`, `I` and `O`, that means replacing `0,A,B…` by `A,B,C…`, replacing `H,I,J…` by `J,K,L…` and replacing `M,N,O…` by `P,Q,R…` (and everything back on deserialisation) - which might be OK if JS has a numeric `char` datatype, but I think it's easier to do it manually as above.

If you're curious:

```
String.prototype.padLeft = function(n, x) {
     return (new Array(n).join(x || "0")+this).slice(-n);
};
function getNext(num) {
    var alphabet = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var back = {}, forth = {};
    for (var i=0; i<alphabet.length; i++) {
        var a = alphabet[i],
            b = i.toString(36);
        back[a] = b;
        forth[b] = a;
    }
    return (parseInt(num.replace(/./g, function(c) {
        return back[c]; // base33 from alphabet
    }), alphabet.length) + 1)
      .toString(alphabet.length)
      .padLeft(3)
      .replace(/./g, function(c) {
        return forth[c]; // base33 to alphabet
      });
}
```