# I need to generate a serial number length specified by option tag of html

Tags: javascript, html

the html option code is here below.

```
<select name="select">
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
</select>
<button id="set">Set Length</button>
<h2>This button generate random number.</h2>    
<button id="btn" onclick="generate()">Generate a serial number</button>
```

This is the javascript code where it generates the a serial number. Setting the length of numbers. The code does not work, can you help.I want the option value to be the one choose the length of the serial number that is generated.

```
function generate() {

'use strict';

var chars = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

function set()
{

    var length = document.getElementsByName('select'),

    lengthValue = document.getElementByTagName('option').value,

    serialLength = lengthValue,

    randomSerial = '',

    randomNumber,

    i;

   randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);

    for (i = 0; i < serialLength; i++) 
    {

        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);

        // validations for the loop.

        if(chars === chars) 
        {

        randomSerial += chars.substring(randomNumber, randomNumber - 1);

        }   
        //randomSerial += chars.substring(randomNumber, randomNumber + 1);
    }
    document.getElementById('set').addEventListener('click',set);

} 
document.getElementById('serial').innerHTML = randomSerial;
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741159/how-to-create-a-alphanumeric-serial-number-in-javascript

Comment: `if(chars === chars)` ...? What exactly is that supposed to do? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4L52a7j1/